# ENV not connecting to component in React

Tags: reactjs, api, sdk, environment-variables

I can't tell if this is an issue with the SDK I am using (Alchemy) or if it's me improperly configuring my .env, but I am trying to use an API key to configure a new Alchemy object like so:

```
const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    network: Network.ETH_MAINNET,
  };
  const alchemy = new Alchemy(config);
```

But I get errors with connections. When I hard code my actual api into the field as a string:
`apiKey: "my api key";`, it works and connects properly. Obviously I will not deploy this or push this to github because of security reasons.

I've also tried
`apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY`, and that failed as well.

My `.env` sits in the root directory of my React app folder and I can promise that there isn't any spelling or grammar errors when trying to access the api key from `.env`